# While loop with multiple conditions until one condition is met, in python

Tags: python, while-loop, multiple-conditions

ORIGINAL:

I'm trying to have a while loop that checks two conditions and stops if one condition is met.
My exact needs are something that goes like this

```
while integer1 AND integer2 > 0:
  # perform calculation and print results at each instance of the loop
```

REPHRASING:
I need to make a loop that runs until one of two numbers becomes zero, and each of those numbers will change during each iteration of the loop.

Sorry if my original phrasing was confusing, hope this makes more sense.

Comment: "but closes if one condition is met" - sounds like you're looking for an `or` - not an `and`

Comment: Is that code snippet not working? What is the question being asked? If it's not doing what you want, perhaps you should say in words (not code) what you want it to do. Something like, "The loop continues while the first integer is greater than zero and the second integer is greater than zero."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integers except 0 assumes as `True` by python when you use them as condition so actually you have , and note that `and` (not AND) operand works works for chain 2 condition!:

```
while True and integer2 > 0:
```

instead you need :

```
while integer1 > 0 and integer2 > 0:
```

But if you want to make a loop that runs until one of two numbers becomes zero you need and and you need to decrees your integers inside the loop!

```
while integer1 > 0 and integer2 > 0:
   #do stuff
   #for example integer1 -=1
   #integer2 -=1
```

Comment: OR means it will continue until both are negative, which I don't think is what the question is asking, although due to the wording, I'm not sure.

Comment: Wouldn't that close the loop if integer1 became less than integer2 but was still above 0?

Comment: @user3759953 if you want to make a loop that runs until one of two numbers becomes zero you need `and` and you need to decrees your integers inside the loop!

Comment: thank you. I used 'AND'  to try to make it obvious that it was an and, not an or. Inside the loop both numbers do decrease but they decrease at uneven rates and I needed to stop the loop when one became zero or less than zero/ Thank you.

Comment: @user3759953 welcome! its OK , you can decrease on uneven rates!;)

Comment: @user3759953 you're welcome, so you can tell this to community by voting and accepting the answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose one could use:

```
while all([x > 0 for x in a,b,c]):
    be_happy()
```

... in other words you could use a list comprehension expression and test `all()` on that.

For only two variables this would be a bit obtuse.  I'd just use:

```
while a > 0 and b > 0:
```

... but for more than two I'd suggest all.  You can use a list comprehension as shown or you could use a generator expression thus:

```
while all((x>0 for x in (a,b,c))):
```

... as shown it seems to be necessary to enclose the tuple in (parentheses) in this case whereas it wasn't necessary in my test of my earlier example.

Personally I think the list comprehension is marginally more readable.  But that may be more subjective than anything.

Also note that you can use the `any()` built-in for the rather obvious alternatively semantics.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers look like they'll solve your problem, but to explain why your code isn't working, both sides of an AND expression are treated as separate conditions and will become either true or false. You're not saying "while both integer1 and integer2 are greater than zero", you saying, "while integer1 is not false and while integer2 is greater than zero". Note that those are two separate conditions.

On the right, when integer2 is greater than zero,

```
integer2 > 0
```

will turn into True for the condition. On the left, however,

```
integer1
```

is the whole condition, and it will turn into true when it is not zero. See [Python Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html)